# objective c and iphone map route issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been using this link to get polyline points from content of this link

I have this expression to get polyline points

```
NSString* apiUrlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps??output=dragdir&saddr=%@&daddr=%@", saddr, daddr];

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"points:\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\"" options:0 error:NULL];

NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:apiResponse options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [apiResponse length])];

NSString *encodedPoints = [apiResponse substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]];
```

But this code returns `encodedPoints` to `nil` in response

This is response from the  link above in XCode:

link to the code: [RESPONSE Content](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4Y-Fs1oJQLOYjk1TGg2VWpsc1E)

How could I get encoded points using regular expression?
What is the problem in my code? It was working fine before 2 days. I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Is `apiResponse` nil? Or is your Regex the issue? Show what looks like `apiResponse`.

Comment: You need to debug your code. Linking to external code is generally not acceptable. So narrow it down and include it in your question.

Comment: apiResponse is given in the link.. i don't get encodePoints

Comment: @dandan78 should i narraw google response code? how could you know where is the problem if i paste narrowed code? even i can't get the issue

Comment: You receive a HTML document response? There is not WebService that give response in JSON or XML? Because if they decided to change the format of their html page, you'd get stucked. That what possibly happened.

Comment: Clearly, in "apiResponse", there is no where the string "points:" That why you regex fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should to use a WebService. Google Maps provides [API](https://developers.google.com/maps/).

Your issue is that you're downloading the web page. You said it was working two days ago? Well, they may have change their page since then.
 
For example, there is nowhere the string "`points:`" in the document. That why your regex fails. If tomorrow they change the source code of their page (as it may have happened since two days ago), you're good to redo it, whereas an API should not change (or at least keeps it working for a few moments, years, etc. the deprecated version).